# How do I get regex hits with patterns that contain spaces when using Solr?

Tags: regex, solr

I am new to Solr and I am having issues with regex searches where the match may contain spaces.

One example would be a search for a phone number with area code.

I index the following string:

call me on 01234 567890

In this instance my regex is: /[0-9{5} ?[0-9]{6}/

which creates the url:

http://localhost:8983/solr/core/select?q=content%3A%2F%28[0-9]{5}%29+%3F%28[0-9]{6}%29%2F&wt=xml&indent=true

but i do not get any hits.

My schema.xml contains the following:

```
<fieldType name="general_text" class="solr.TextField" omitNorms="true" positionIncrementGap="100">
          <analyzer type="index">
          <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory" />
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
          </analyzer>
        <analyzer type="query">
          <tokenizer class="solr.UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory" />              
          <filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory" /> 
        </analyzer>
      </fieldType>

<field name="content" type="general_text" indexed="true" stored="true" required="false" multiValued="true" />
```

I may need to run different regexes after the data has been indexed so i don't think using a PatternTokenizerFactory would work in my case. I am using the UAX29URLEmailTokenizerFactory because I need to identify email addresses.
Is it possible to perform a regex search with spaces in this manner?

Could someone please advice me on what changes I need to make to achieve these regex hits?

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of approaches. For both, you define a new field type and a new field and use copyField to send the text for "content" to the second field.

One approach is to copy the text to another field that does not tokenize. That will preserve the spaces for pattern matching. Use a string field type and the keyword tokenizer (which makes the entire input a single keyword). Run your regex queries against that field.

If phone numbers are a common use case, make a field type that ignores everything but phone numbers. I did something like this for ISBNs. The last step, with the LengthFilterFactory, is important, because zero-length tokens have some odd behavior.

```
<tokenizer class="solr.KeywordTokenizerFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.LowerCaseFilterFactory"/>
<filter class="solr.TrimFilterFactory"/>
<!-- Remove anything that isn’t a digit or an 'x'. -->
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory"
    pattern="[^\dx]" replacement="" replace="all"/>
<!-- ISBNs and EANs are either 10 or 13 characters long. -->
<filter class="solr.LengthFilterFactory" min="10" max="13"/>
```

Using more than one field for the same text is a very powerful technique. It allows multiple views of the same text with different matching techniques. You can have lightly-processed text (tokenized, lowercased) for fuzzy matching, stemmed text, and phonetic text, all in the same index.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it has got me a little closer. I tried your first suggestion, unfortunately now I need a regex that matches the entire line. So in the case I outlined above I would get a hit with the following: /[a-z ]*[0-9]{5} [0-9]{6}/ but nothing if I use: /[0-9]{5} [0-9]{6}/

Comment: Use the Analysis page in the admin UI to see the result of the steps in the analysis chain. It is fantastic for debugging this sort of thing.